# Adding new content type to existing libraries

Tags: content-type, libraries

A common issue with my customers is that they define a number of content types that should be available on a document library. That library is part of a custom site template and pretty soon we'll have 200 sites using that template. 
Now the customer realize that they need two new content types on that library. Oh, and they will need those content types on the existing sites as well.

I might have misunderstod something about content types or just misconfigured the library, but so far the only way I have been able to add those new content types on existing sites have been through a powershell script.

Is this just a feature in SharePoint 2007 that I'll have to get used to, or have I missed a crucial point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content types are scoped to a site, so the only way to make them visible on all sites is to activate the containing feature at the root of every site collection.

Once the content type is added to the gallery, it can be selected in the browser. (You need to change the library to allow management of content types.) However, your PowerShell approach will certainly be easier than visiting every site/library to add it.